# «Какую» или «какая»?

Tags: окончания

Допустим, одна женщина говорит другой о том, какое отношение к себе ей желательно: «Любите какую есть» или «Любите какая есть»? Местоимения не хочу вставлять. «Какую» или «какая», господа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Любите (такой), какая есть.**

Сложноподчиненное предложение, главное и придаточное предложения неполные.

**КАКАЯ** – союзное слово в придаточном предложении ***какая (я) есть.*** Является именной частью сказуемого **(И.п.)**

**Запятую желательно поставить.** У Розенталя есть тема: § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Но такие сочетания нужно отличать от неполных придаточных.

Сравнить:

***бери какая есть*** (о какой-либо вещи, то есть других нет),

но: ***люби (такой), какая есть***.

Пример:

Ужасайся не ужасайся ...придётся тебе **принять меня, какая есть.** [И. Грекова. Летом в городе (1962)]

Comment: А как по-Вашему, мой вариант "такую" тоже возможен или только "такой" может быть?

Comment: Я догадывалась, Артем, что вы меня об этом спросите. В Нацкорпусе есть варианты "такой, какая", но нет варианта "такую, какая". Я думаю,  что это связано с тем, что В.п. обозначает определенное качество (конкретность и определенность - это характерное свойство В.п.). А вот Т.п. может обозначать проявление разных качеств человека, которые в общем составляют его индивидуальность.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

> *Любите (такую), как**ая** (я) есть.*

Comment: Запятая, наверное, нужна. Но смотрится всё равно ужасно :)

Comment: Возможно. Я тоже понимал, что её можно поставить. Но к сугубо разговорному, не очень правильному примеру сложно подходить с правилами, под него не продуманными.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5659#p306397) нечто схожее, но ни одного примера с "какая". В самого Розенталя лень сейчас смотреть. Наверное-таки нужна. Но пусть кто-нибудь другой подтвердит/опровергнет, я не уверен.

Comment: Вы с Sharon убедили меня. Поставлю запятую.